# Page won't load after setting up ssl

Tags: apache, ssl, server, lets-encrypt

Hello everyone I just setup ssl support with certbot and everything went good but it won't load the page unless I enter the full url to the login.

I am running an apache server on linode. I think i have to set up a redirect but when I do the page won't load and says to many redirects.

I am not sure what information you would need to help me out but whatever it is just let me know. Thank's in advance.

-James

Comment: Are you using any CMS? What kind of redirects do you have set up that it's saying there's too many? This tool can be useful to trace your redirects and help debug: http://www.wheregoes.com/   Also, if it's easy to remove your SSL, can you try doing that and seeing if the page loads again?

Comment: Yea we have an app creator and its cms. Its weird because when I directly enter the url its goes to the login if you click the link from the platform it only shows a blank screen and just eb4app.com nothing after that. I will check out wheregoes.com. (update)I just fixed it i am such a dummy on the main server it was still pointing to an http address now its https: Thank you for your help and reply.